# Regarding TOAD for Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, toad

Is TOAD an open-source tool for developing applications.

I am planning to develop application in JAVA and exploring options on DataBase.
I am building an Enterprise Application.Kindly let me know which will be best Databse for this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is TOAD an open-source tool for developing applications

No it's a licenced (non free) tool for connecting and working with databases.

> I am planning to develop application in JAVA

I believe Eclipse is the usual free tool used for Java development

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/java.php

> Kindly let me know which will be best Databse for this requirement

Based on what requirements? If it needs to be free or open source, follow the MySQL and PostgreSQL suggestions, assuming it is a relational database you are after.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want an open source DB.  If that is the case mySql and PostgreSQL are both well respected Enterprise DBs.  However based upon what you have specified it is hard to know what is suitable for your unknown application.